# MySQL server exception when inserting row from Android app

Tags: android, jdbc

I am trying to insert a record in a MySQL table from an android app using JDBC.

This is my code:

```
 try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ipServidor, usuario, password); //Connection Object
                Log.d("MPI DESARROLLO","main syncdata try connect="+conn);

                if (conn == null) {
                    btnConectar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    success = false;
                } else {

                    String q = "INSERT INTO sesiones (id,numerosesion,fechasesion) VALUES ("+5+","+5+","+fechahora+")";

                    String query =q;
                    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

                    int res = stmt.executeUpdate(q);
                    if(res>0){
                        //success

                    }else{
                        //failed
                        Log.d("insert","insert NO ok");
                    }


                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Writer writer = new StringWriter();
                e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(writer));
                msg = writer.toString();
                Log.d("insert","insert "+msg);
                success = false;
            }
```

I am getting an exception, this is the log for it:

```
insert java.sql.SQLException: Syntax error or access violation message from server: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '14:24:10)' at line 1"
```

I guess the exception is due to the variable fechasesion, this is its value:

feecha hora `2019-03-26 14:24:10`

I think it is right, but for some reason, the server doesn't accept it.

Comment: You really should NOT be using JDBC in an andorid app.  Doing so requires your app to have the password to your db, which is totally insecure.  Everything should go to your db via web service.

Comment: @GabeSechan, thanks, I know, but security is not an issue in this case. The app will be used in a local network and all users are co-workers. It doesn't matter to put all db credentials inside the app code. And the client doesn't want to install any extra files on the server

Answer (score 0):

It is solved, I needed to put the datetime value inside quotes:

```
String q = "INSERT INTO sesiones (id,numerosesion,fechasesion) VALUES ("+5+","+5+","+"'"+fechahora+"'"+")";
```